# initramfs / UUID problems after cloning

Tags: cloning, clonezilla

So I just cloned a Centos7 "everything install" VM to a physical disk using VMWare Workstation and Clonezilla using the instructions here:
https://www.howtoforge.com/converting-a-vmware-image-to-a-physical-machine-p2

Now, when the clone (physical disk) boots up, it drops into the command line with this:

> ```
> dracut-initqueue[417]: Warning: Could not boot. dracut-initqueue[417]:
> Warning: /dev/disk/by-uuid/4b8b5627-9027-46f7-b722-61d3ddd28e74 does
> not exist Starting dracut emergency shell...
> ```

What I've tried:

- I checked /etc/fstab and the proper UUIDs are there, including the one above.
- Tried booting into USB rescue mode, chroot /mnt/sysimage , and:

  ```
  mv /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r).img /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r)-oh_crud.img
  ```

  and then

  ```
  dracut /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r).img $(uname -r)
  ```

  ...but I get this:

  > cat: write error: Broken pipe

Additional notes:

- When I enter:

  ```
  blkid
  ```

  I see the HD in question showing up as both `/dev/block` and /dev/sdb`
- I tried:

  ```
  lshw -class disk
  ```

  but it says "command not found".
- The rescue shell is mounting my disk in `/mnt/sysimage` and all my files are there, so it appears it is seeing and mounting the HD.

Comment: mikeserv- I don't understand. The UUID for the disk shown by "blkid" matches what is in /etc/fstab. What do you suggest I change the UUID to?

Comment: mikeserv- the source disk (the disk that was cloned) is a VM and does not exist on this machine, so why would there be a UUID conflict?

Comment: mikeserv- gotchya. BIOS on both.

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas. Sorry. The best suggesttion I can make is rebuilding initramfs on the baremetal clone with `dracut`.

Comment: I would guess you actually are missing a kernel module, so the hardware isn't showing. Do you have any disks showing up in your rescue shell? Are there any other error messages, further up?

Comment: @derobert - ahh, yeah! don't `vmware` disks mount as some kind of `vmware` block dev with the kernel headers they insert? Or maybe thats `vbox`... still, I think `vmware` has those *guest modules* or whatever - and it would be strange to include much else but those in a kernel targeted for virtual machine install. I think you're probably right on.

Comment: derobert- how do I determine if any other disks are showing up in my rescue shell (note I am booting into rescue shell from USB installer if that matters)? I see the HD in question showing up when I type "blkid" as both /dev/block... and /dev/sdb...I tried "lshw -class disk" but it says command not found. Finally, the rescue shell says it is mounting my disk in /mnt/sysimage and all my files appear to be there.

Comment: EDIT: original post updated to indicate rescue shell is mounting my HD.

Comment: Did you ever try just using /dev/sdb1 or whichever instead of the UUID?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and found that running `uname -r` didn't return the correct kernel version under rescue mode that I was using normally.

I had to check what initramfs file grub was trying to boot from by pressing <kbd>e</kbd> at the grub boot screen and then once in rescue mode do something like this -

```
cd /boot
initramfs -f initramfs-3.10.0-327.4.4.el7.x86_64.img 3.10.0-327.4.4.el7.x86_64
```

`uname -r` in my case was just returning "3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64" which wasn't the kernel version I was trying to load from grub (3.10.0-327.4.4).

I wonder if your lack of the `-f` switch or a mismatch of the kernel versions used by rescue mode and normal mode may be your issue here